# Why are my output file sizes different when using CSC.EXE vs. Devenv?

Tags: visual-studio, nant, csc

I am playing with Nant and CSC. I notice that a debug version of my dll is 140k if compiled via CSC and nant build scripts. However if i build a debug version in the Visual Studio env, it is at 203k!? the smaller DLL DOES appear to work fine in the main program however. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/csharpgeneral/thread/74db169a-e244-496e-ae97-8dfec18ff2e5

Also there may be some additions by VS when compiling nor to "clean" csc.exe

Comment: No, this is a completely different question